# What precisely does cp -b (--backup) actually do?

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, options, coreutils

Before you hit me with the obvious, I know, the backup option makes a backup of a file.

But the thing is, the `cp` command in general backs up a file. One could argue a copy of a file is a backup.

So more precisely, my question is this: what does the `-b` option do that the `cp` command doesn't do already?

The cp(1) man page gives the following description of the `--backup` option:

> make a backup of each existing destination file

This definition isnt very useful, basically saying "the backup option makes a backup". This gives no indication as to what `-b` adds to the `cp`

I know `-b` puts some suffix at the end of the name of the new file. But is there anything else it does? Or is that it? Is a `-b` backup just a `cp` command that adds something to the end of the filename? Thank you

P.S. Do you typically use `-b` when making backups in your daily work? Or do you just stick to `-a`?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/893610/158442 and https://askubuntu.com/a/577043/158442 for some uses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes a backup copy of each destination file that already exists. The ones that would otherwise get overwritten and lost.

```
$ mkdir foo; cd foo
$ echo hello > hello.txt
$ echo world > world.txt
$ cp -b hello.txt world.txt
$ ls
hello.txt  world.txt~  world.txt
$ cat world.txt
hello
$ cat world.txt~
world
```

That `world.txt~` being the backup file it created. If you look closely, you'll see that the backup file is actually the original file, just renamed. (i.e. the inode number stays the same, and so do e.g. the permissions of that file.)

Comment: Ooooh, when you make a copy and the copy is named "abc.txt", but a file named "abc.txt" already exists in that folder, instead of simply overwriting the existing "abc.txt" with our copy, or leaving the existing "abc.txt" alone and not making our copy altogether, it instead RENAMES THE EXISTING "abc.txt" to "abc.txt~" (or something else if you configure it to), THEN puts our new copy named "abc.txt" in that folder! The inode of "abc.txt" before the cp is the same as the inode of "abc.txt~" after the cp!


               IDK why the wording was just not clicking for me before now. Thank you!

Comment: @backslashenn, exactly! (`cp -n` would be the one that skips doing the copy if the target exists)

Answer (score 2):

From the same (GNU coreutils) cp manpage:

```
       --backup[=CONTROL]
              make a backup of each existing destination file
```

So, natural, we look for the definition of `CONTROL` in that document:

```
       The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.  The version control method may be selected via the --backup option or through the VERSION_CONTROL environment variable.  Here are the values:

       none, off
              never make backups (even if --backup is given)

       numbered, t
              make numbered backups

       existing, nil
              numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise

       simple, never
              always make simple backups
```

> But is there anything else it does?

no.

> P.S. Do you typically use -b when making backups in your daily work? Or do you just stick to -a?

Hm. `-b` sounds like a bad solution for actual backing up data. It's more for avoiding to damage data in non-backup situations. So, no, I've *never* used `-b`.

For backup, it really depends on the context, but for private/small filesystem stuff, filesystem snapshots (either through ZFS or by virtue of using thin LVM below) work very nicely. For off-device backups, it's honestly mostly `rsync` for complete backups. For things where you want incremental backups off-disk, `duplicity` is OK.

Comment: Annoyingly, the man page doesn't say what the default value of `CONTROL` is, i.e., which of the four behaviors is active when `--backup` is given without an argument.